# How do flash fires occur?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I don't quite understand the prerequisites for a flash fire. Moreover, why don't they last long? Basically what is the general mechanism behind them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash fires can be one of two things: pre-mixed gas phase combustion or dispersed combustible solid particle/liquid droplet combustion.

#### Pre-mixed gas phase combustion

A pool of flammable liquid or a gas leak will produce a flammable vapour/air mixture above the pool surface or location of the leak. This can extend beyond the surface of the pool. This mixture will be beyond the lower flammability limit. If an ignition source is introduced to this flammable mixture the flame will rapidly propagate through the vapour mixture. This produces a large, transient diffusion flame. The extent of this flame will depend on the vapour pressure of the liquid, local wind, atmospheric turbulence.

#### Suspended particle/droplet combustion

A very efficient form of combustion and is often used in industry (e.g. combustion chamber of a diesel engine). Caused by ignition of a mix of air and combustible solid particles (e.g. "dust") or liquid droplets (e.g. a high pressure hydraulic leak). Suspended solid particles/liquid droplets ahead of the flame front are very rapidly vapourised to form flammable vapour. Evaporation is very rapid due to high surface-to-volume ratio. This forms a very rapidly travelling flame front. Fuel is rapidly consumed, hence duration is low.

### Sum up

#### Pre-requisites

Pre-mixed flammable vapour/air mixture from a liquid pool/leak or suspended-in-air combustible solid particles/liquid droplets. Ignition source.

#### Short duration

Fuel is very rapidly consumed, due to efficiency of burning.

#### General mechanism

Ignition of a pre-mixed combustible gas/air or combustible particle/air mixture.

Answer (score 1):

Combustion requires a certain amount of air (oxygen) to actually burn.  If you take something and spread it out; you increase the surface area exposed to air.

A basic summary is that there's more air able to react with the burning particles.  As long as there is enough air; the burning can take place, so by having more contact with air, more can burn at once.  This leads to a very quick intense fire.

Just a side note, this is more chemistry than physics (as an answer, the chemical phoemoneon obviously can be broken down to physics if you needed to examine physical properties).